# which formula to use for this sum?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

From a class of $250$ students a sample of $64$ students was taken and the mean height was found to be $160$ cms with a standard deviation of $16$ cms. What is the range in which the mean height of students of the class is expected to lie?

Comment: What is the relationship between population vs. sample mean and standard deviation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance